# Stripe cc entry form does not appear on front and backend

Tags: stripe

WP 6.2 Civi 5.61.4 PHP 7.4 Stripe 6.6 OR 6.8.2

The "window" for entering cc details doesn't appear. Backend or front end - logged in or out.
Have "payment shared, firewall and sweet alert installed

Browser console:

```
GET https://www.******/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.recentmenu/js/recentmenu.js?r=mho5ien_US net::ERR_ABORTED 404
www.******/:137     GET https://www.******/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/mjwshared/js/crm.payment.js?r=mho5ien_US net::ERR_ABORTED 404
www.******/:147     GET https://www.******/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/sweetalert/css/sweetalert2.min.css?r=mho5ien_US net::ERR_ABORTED 404
www.******/:148     GET https://www.******/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/sweetalert/js/sweetalert2.min.js?r=mho5ien_US 404
www.******/:150     GET https://www.******/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/custom/?r=mho5ien_US net::ERR_ABORTED 404
www.******/:327     GET https://www.******/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/css/civi-button-inputs.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404
www.******/:727     GET https://www.******/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.drastikbydesign.stripe/js/civicrmStripe.js?r=mho5ien_US net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

Comment: Could you please say a bit more about what you've tried already?  In particular: 
What happens if you try to visit the URLs that give 404s directly?  Are the file permissions correct? Do you have access to the web server logs to see if there's any redirection happening?

Comment: Have you selected the amount?

Comment: Hi Pradeep yes I select amount but stripe cc entry form does not appear

Comment: Hi Jon URLs direct give 404 - nothing in server log - probably nothing getting that far as stripe just doesn't popup. Have tried reinstalling extension, latest version and 6.6. Upgrading to latest civi 5.61.4, permissions are all 755 or 644. Path is correct. Also changed resource url to absolute path

Comment: More info. I get exactly the same set of 404 errors (minus the stripe one) when using the omnipay payment processor. However that works as expected ie on selection of $amount the Billing fields appear.